# On a Theorem of Lee's book on Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces

The following theorem is from Lee "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds".

Suppose $\widetilde{M}$ is a connected smooth manifold with a discrete group $\Gamma$ acting smoothly, freely and properly on $\widetilde{M}$. Then the quotient map $\pi:\widetilde{M}\to \widetilde{M}/\Gamma$ is a smooth normal covering map.

My question is if the connected assumption on $\widetilde{M}$ necessary? I do not see if this assumption plays any role in the proof. Secondly, how to show that $\Gamma$ acts trasitively on the fibers of $\pi$ ? My third question is if the covering group of $\widetilde{M}/\Gamma$ and $\Gamma$ are isomorphic? Clearly, each element of $\Gamma$ acts as a Deck transformation on $\widetilde{M}$. Is the other way also true?

Comment: A fiber of $\pi$ is exactly a $\Gamma$-orbit, so I guess $\Gamma$ trivially acts transitively on a fiber. I'll follow this question, I'd like to see the answer.

Comment: @Charles. Your comment makes sense. But I was rather confused by the language. I thought on the space of fibers  $\Gamma$ acts transitively, which cant happen for obvious reason. I think as you mentioned on a  fixed given fiber $\Gamma$ acts transitively.

Comment: The connectedness of $\tilde{M}$ is not needed in the proof as such. But if you look at Lee's definition of a covering map, it already requires $\tilde{M}$ to be connected. And in fact, it is pretty reasonable to include the connectedness condition in the definition/ 

Your second question is already answered in the previous comment. In fact, it is not phrased clearly in the proof but if you see the definition of normal covering map (pg. 163) you will see that he mentions that $\pi$ is a normal covering iff $Aut_{\pi}(E)$ actis transitively 'on each fiber' of $\pi.$

Comment: The answer to your third question is yes! And it is not very hard. If you want you can actually see Theorem 12.14 in Introduction to Topological Manifolds by Lee. (Although the proof is relegated to some exercise problem).

Comment: @JackLee${}{}{}$